# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str' in python 3.10

Tags: python, loops

I am learning python online. In one of the lessons it showed how to print 'X' on screen using nested loops as per the list of numbers defined.

I am running following code on python 3. It works fine in the video but it is not working for me.

```py
numbers = [5, 2, 5, 2, 2]
for x_count in numbers:
    output = ''
    for output in range(x_count):
        output += 'x'
    print(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have same variable name as `output` both in the the `output = ''` and in the `for loop` `for output in range(x_count):`, change the variable name to something else to resolve this issue.

```py
numbers = [5, 2, 5, 2, 2]
for x_count in numbers:
    output = ''
    for _ in range(x_count):
        output += 'x'
    print(output)
```